# pm2 not working with experimental-modules flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, es6-modules

I am using ES6 modules by adding the `--experimental-modules` arguments to Node. Running `node --experimental-modules app.mjs` works perfectly fine. However, when I run the same command with pm2 I get the following error:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module

My current pm2 config file looks like this:

```
"apps": [
 {
  "name": "api",
  "script": "app.mjs",
  "exec_mode": "cluster",
  "instances": "max",
  "node_args": "--experimental-modules",
  "env": {
    variables here..
  }
 }
],
```

I have also tried using esm instead like this:

```
"node_args": "-r esm"
```

In both cases they return the same `[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]` error

Does anyone have a solution on how to use es6 modules with pm2 or is it broken at the moment?

Comment: any solutions yet?

Comment: there is still an open issue in pm2 about this node flag https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3294

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

Starting from Node.js version 12.14.1, you don't have to add the `--experimental-modules` argument, so if you update node, it should work without any changes to your configuration.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

A workaround for this problem:

- In your package.json file, add a new script:

```js
  "scripts": {
    //Add this one:
    "safestart":"node --experimental-modules app.mjs"
  },
```

- Run this PM2 command:

```js
pm2 start npm -- run safestart
```

Comment: please share how to run index.mjs with pm2. the sample above doesn't work for me.

Comment: please check the update I provided for the answer @YuriyTigiev

Comment: I have installed pm2@4.2.3 and nothing changed

Comment: With latest lts version v14.15.0 use "type": "module" in package.json and use ecosystem.config.cjs (Note the .cjs extension).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to update node or another approach is using [esm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm)

See my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382237/why-pm2-ignored-the-experimental-modules-passed-to-node-in-the-ecosystem-confi/61632609#61632609)