# Why pm2 ignored the --experimental-modules passed to node in the ecosystem.config.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, es6-modules

This is my `main.js` file:

```
import Koa from "koa";

const app = new Koa();
app.use(async ctx => ctx.body = "Hello, World!");
app.listen(3000);
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "koa-sandbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node --experimental-modules ./src/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

It works fine when I launch it via `npm`:

`npm start`

Now I need to do the same via `pm2`. This is my `ecosystem.config.js`file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'API',
    script: './src/main.js',
    node_args : '--experimental-modules',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
  }],
};
```

I start my application:

`pm2 start .\ecosystem.config.js`

but I see the result:

[image]

In log-file I see it:

```
(node:12696) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
C:\lab\koa-sandbox\src\main.js:1
import Koa from "koa";
       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:22)
```

Why `pm2` ignored the `--experimental-modules` passed to `node` in the `ecosystem.config.js` file?

I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499715/pm2-not-working-with-experimental-modules-flag) but it hasn't answer still...

Answer (score -2):

For using esm `import`s I am using [esm package](http://npmjs.com/package/esm)

You can add a file for example `index.js` and in the file

```
require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require("./main.js")
```

and modify `ecosystem.config.js` to

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'API',
    script: './src/index.js',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
  }],
};
```

In the `package.json` you do not have to

```
"start": "node --experimental-modules ./src/main.js"
```

The script will run without `--experimental-modules`.

just

```
"start": "node ./src/index.js"
```