# pm2 index.js return ERR_REQUIRE_ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, config, pm2

`status` shown as `online` after I run `pm2 start index.js`. 
But once I call API, it return `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM`.

I try to fixed with:

1. rename index.js file to index.mjs and run `pm2 start index.mjs`
2. install `esm` package and run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'backend',
    script: 'index.js',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }]
};
```

which both methods are failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499715/pm2-not-working-with-experimental-modules-flag check this.

Comment: i use nodemon to run the app.